# Emacs, org-mode, evil-mode - TAB key not working

Tags: emacs, org-mode, evil-mode

I've been working with VIM for decades, and I've become quite proficient in it. I was however sort-of... seduced by Emacs's `org-mode`, and in order to try it, I installed Emacs and Evil.

Evil satisfies most of my VIM-related muscle memory, so I proceeded with my testing of `org-mode` - and met my first issue: when I spawn Emacs in its own window (i.e. `emacs plan.org`) then the `TAB` key works, opening and closing my plan's sections just fine. However, `TAB` does nothing when I use Emacs in text mode (i.e inside my XTerms, via "emacs -nw plan.org"). And that's the state that I am mostly interested in, since I usually work from inside screen/tmux over SSH connections.

If it's a conflict with Evil-mode, I don't understand why - I am unaware of any TAB functionality in VIM's normal mode (which is what we're in when opening/closing org-mode sections).

Any Emacs-guru out there with a suggestion on why this happens?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try

```
(setq evil-want-C-i-jump nil)
```

in your ~/.emacs  *before*

```
(require 'evil)
```

Evil has, in evil-maps.el

```
(when evil-want-C-i-jump
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "C-i") 'evil-jump-forward))
```

That should give you org-mode Tab functionality back

Comment: This is very evil functionality.

Comment: This works for me. (Emacs org-mode major mode, in evil-normal-state).

Answer (score 2):

I have almost no experience with terminals. However, I know that TAB is equivalent to C-i. Maybe that one would go through the terminal?  If that works, you could add some key bindings for every TAB operation?

Try maybe C-h k TAB as well to see if TAB if sent on the wire.

Comment: Tried C-i, didn't do anything. I then tried C-h k TAB, but when I hit 'C-h', I get a 'Beginning of line' message printed at the bottom line - maybe Evil intercepts this key combo?

Comment: After further investigation: you probably meant C-c C-i (sorry, I am rather ignorant in Emacs things), which *does* work. Is there anything I can add to my .emacs to map 'TAB' to C-c C-i when run under consoles? (XTerms, etc)

Comment: you can do that: `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'org-cycle)`. Indeed TAB didn't work in the console (was bound to evil-jump-forward).

Comment: or try (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-i") 'org-cycle)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "M-i") 'evil-jump-forward)
 (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "M-o") 'evil-jump-backward)
```

I bind the function to other keys, so it's also work.